# When to use the Kappa statistic evaluation metric?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, precision-recall, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

Can someone tell me when is it appropriate to use the Kappa statistic? Also why to use it when one can use Area Under the ROC curve? Or even the Area under the precision-recall curve? So what are the differences between them?!

Comment: Are you speaking of various ways to convey the 2x2 confusion frequency table (true state X classification state)?

Comment: For those still interested, there's an interesting discussion of ROC AUC v. PR AUC on a blog [here](http://dpmartin42.github.io/blogposts/r/imbalanced-classes-part-2). Didn't see anything clearly comparing with Cohen's Kappa as well though.

Comment: None of these measures are proper accuracy scoring rules.  See [this](http://fharrell.com/post/class-damage).